# How to chop the last "/script.sh" part from a string?

Tags: shell

How could I modify this INPUT:

```
/home/USER/Desktop/script.sh
```

to this OUTPUT:

```
/home/USER/Desktop/
```

...using `bash` or `perl`?

Of course `script.sh` could be anything: (e.g. `scrasdfipt.sh`, etc) and the path before it could be anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dirname /home/USER/Desktop/script.sh`

Answer (score 4):

For the **exact** question, you can use

```
printf "$(dirname /home/USER/Desktop/script.sh)/"
```

I'm guessing this is an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), and you want to refer to a file in *the same directory as the current script*. If so:

```
current_dir="$(dirname -- "$0")"
```

At this point you can do stuff like

```
source "${current_dir}/foo.sh"
echo foo > "${current_dir}/bar.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using bash:

```
$ dirname -- "$string"
```

You can also get the last bit the same way like this:

```
$ basename -- "$string"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [`dirname`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17589/how-to-chop-the-last-script-sh-part-from-a-string/17592#17592) proposed, you can also remove a susbstring using [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal):

```
dir=/home/USER/Desktop/script.sh
echo ${dir%/*}
/home/USER/Desktop
```

Comment: Note that if the original string contains no directory information, `$dir` will end up identical to it. Fix: `case "$file" in */*) dir="${file%/}";; *) dir=".";; esac`